# Need to get date from previous Google Sheet page inside content without having Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do some automated work in Google Sheet. I have a question below is my subject content which I have in one Google Sheet and the datea and other properties are in other google sheet.

```
Request to stop the production for 01/15/2024 at 10:00 PM PM EST
```

The above date and time should come from previous sheet without using Apps Script.

I am having this content in different sheet if i try to put = and get the value from previous sheet that is not coming since this entire sentence in column.

Comment: `I am having this content in Different sheet if i try to put = and get the value from previous sheet that is not coming since this entire sentence in column.` I don't understand what this means. Would you please edit the question to describe what you are trying to do, provide some sample data, and explain how and where a successful outcome should appear.

Comment: @Tedinoz what I am looking is the date and time should come from previous sheet I tried using =A2 like this i tried  it didn't worked because my entire sentence in single row I am looking for a solution here.

Comment: What is previous sheet? Where is it located? What is the desired output? Simply the cell content?

Comment: @Mr.M Could you provide a sample spreadsheet with some data and result that you want to achieve with the formulas, please?